# Replacing the background in a table

Tags: html, powershell

When executing `$status = $job.LastStatus` shows success or false.

How to do if success then `tg-aff0{background-color:#00B050`

and if false, then `tg-aff0{background-color:#FB9895`

```
$job = Get-VBOJob -name jobname
$status = $job.LastStatus
$name = $job.Name
$job_stats_get = Get-VBOJobSession -Job $job -Last
$job_stats_get.statistics


$EmailBody = @"
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-aff0{background-color:#00B050;color:#ffffff;border-color:inherit;font-size:36px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
```

Comment: Hey @andrew, happy to assist. Can you please review this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? and update your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell? You should specify the programming language used.

Comment: Strange, I used the powershell tag, the changes were not saved

Comment: Note: the `type="text/css"` attribute is the default. You don't need to keep that.